# WebClient max header size

Tags: spring-webflux, response-headers, reactor-netty

Is there any way I can configure the max header size for a response?

I get the following error from the netty framework :

```
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.newException(HttpObjectDecoder.java:983)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Apparently reactor [added an API](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/531) for this, but I don't see how is this controllable in the WebClient of spring Web Flux. I am using the following version

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try setting `server.max-http-header-size` in `application.properties`

Comment: I think what the question meant was on response of WebClient response while `server.max-http-header-size` limits size on incoming requests if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure reactor's `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` to have custom `maxHeaderSize` and plug this preconfigured `HttpClient` in your WebClient instance.

```java
HttpClient httpClient =
    HttpClient.create().httpResponseDecoder(spec -> spec.maxHeaderSize(32 * 1024));

WebClient webClient =
    WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .build();
```

Comment: This worked for me but I am wondering why the server.max-http-header-size=65536 didn't work in spring boot app version 2.xx

Comment: `server.max-http-header-size` configures the max header size that the server can accept. My answer is a client configuration instead.

Answer (score 2):

In a Spring Boot app, the max HTTP header size is configured using:

```
server.max-http-header-size=65536
```

I have found this solved the above issue on spring cloud gateway, so worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I got problem like this. I can open this link by google chrome, by terminal. It's ok, but if i use webClient, i got problem about size of headers.
I use a lot of methods for resolve this problem.

As a result, I tried to use OkHttpClient, and got correct result!!!:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://example.com")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val responseBody: ResponseBody? = response.body
            val responseString = responseBody?.string()
            println(responseString)
        } else {
            println("Error: ${response.code}")
        }
    }
```